# The template you have chosen is invalid or cannot be found

Tags: sharepoint

> Exception in frmMPInstall.CreateSite: Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: The template you have chosen is invalid or cannot be found. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x81071E44): The template you have chosen is invalid or cannot be found. at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.ApplyWebTemplate(String bstrUrl, String& bstrWebTemplate, Int32& plWebTemplateId) at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.ApplyWebTemplate(String bstrUrl, String& bstrWebTemplate, Int32& plWebTemplateId) --- End of inner exception stack trace

At the time of Deploying the solution.It shows above error .
It happened only in 64 bit processor.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve this problem as described here: [SharePoint SiteDefinitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171489/sharepoint-sitedefinitions/2919457#2919457)

Answer (score 0):

*Wild guess warning*

SharePoint is targeting the 'Program Files (x86)' folder to get the definition when your files are in the actual 'Program Files' folder or vice-versa. See if you can define those within your Setup.

Answer (score 0):

Yep. Glad I documented this when I ran into it. I consulted my trusty SharePoint decoder ring and came up with the following answer for you:

This error comes from a (COM) method called SPRequestInternalClass.ApplyWebTemplate(String bstrUrl, String& bstrWebTemplate, Int32& plWebTemplateId) located inside the Microsoft.SharePoint.Library namespace. It basically means that you are trying to use a site definition ID that is already in use.

Ex:  10023 MYSITEDEF#0 / 10023 IALREADYEXIST#0

Gotta love those hidden COM objects.